# How to do row transformations in Azure ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've a On premise SQL server for which I've configured IR. I want to execute query and transform the output of the query into JSON object. My JSON transformation is complex so can't be done in SQL Server itself. After transformation I need to store the output into ADLSv2. How this can be done in ADF? Ideally I want to write a Python code for doing the row transformations. Can someone suggest me some solution?

Comment: You can use Data Flow to create the source with the SQL query, and then using Derived column to build the JSON schema and mapping the row data according your request. Set the ADLS as the sink. Your question is not very clear and we can answer you directly. It should focus on one question and give our more details.

Comment: Sorry , I forget that Data Flow doesn't support SQL Server. Can you get the expected JSON output by [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) query? If no, then I would suggest wirte a Python code for doing the row transformation.

Comment: How do we call the Python code? I was thinking there will be a way to iterate query results and call Python code. Another side question is how to use IR from Python?

Comment: The data volume is very high I'm talking about over 100million rows. Using forjson will not work

Comment: use databricks. ref here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python

Comment: Hi @kesavkolla, hope you're doing well. Just for now, the data factory active may couldn't meet your request and can't achieve that directly. Without Data Flow, we can't modify the source schema. Other way is achieve it in code lever. If you want to run the python code with your native/on-premise SQL Server. Maybe you could use Databricks python active according the link in above comment. I'm sorry I can't test that for you,  hope you can try it, that's the only way. Hope it's helpful for you. May I post it as answer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes I'm leaning towards spark for achieving this.

Comment: You're welcome, may I post this as answer?

Comment: Hi @kesavkolla, hope you're doing well.  If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to build the JSON schema for your source query output, the only way is use Data Flow. Bu it's on-premise SQL Server and Data Flow doesn't support self-hosted integration runtime. We can't use it.

The only way is that achieve that in code level, like you said write a Python code for doing the row transformations. About the scenario, you can ref this document: [Transform data by running a Python activity in Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python).

I'm glad that you are leaning towards spark for achieving this. Hope everything goes well.

HTH.